# Spark Local Mode - all jobs only use one CPU core

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

We are running Spark Java in local mode on a single AWS EC2 instance using

`"local[*]"`

However, profiling using New Relic tools and a simple 'top' show that only one CPU core of our 16 core machine is ever in use for three different Java spark jobs we've written (we've also tried different AWS instances but only one core is ever used).

`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` reports 16 processors and 
`sparkContext.defaultParallelism()` reports 16 as well.

I've looked at various Stackoverflow local mode issues but none seem to have resolved the issue.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Process

1) Use sqlContext to read gzipped CSV file 1 using com.databricks.spark.csv from disc (S3) into DataFrame DF1.

2) Use sqlContext to read gzipped CSV file 2 using com.databricks.spark.csv from disc (S3) into DataFrame DF2.

3) Use DF1.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new mapping function that returns a Tuple>) RDD1

4) Use DF2.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new mapping function that returns a Tuple>) RDD2

5) Call union on the RDDs

6) Call reduceByKey() on the unioned RDDs to "merge by key" so have a Tuple>) with only one instance of a particular key (as the same key appears in both RDD1 and RDD2).

7) Call .values().map(new mapping Function which iterates over all items in the provided List and merges them as required to return a List of the same or smaller length

8) Call .flatMap() to get an RDD

9) Use sqlContext to create a DataFrame from the flat map of type DomainClass

10) Use DF.coalease(1).write() to write the DF as gzipped CSV to S3.

Comment: How many partitions in your dataset?  If you only have one, you won't benefit from parallelism.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the reply. I am using Spark CSV to read two large CSV files into Dataframes, then converting them to JavaRDDs and performing many manual transformation and merge operations on these RDDs resulting in one Dataframe. I again use SparkCSV to write to disk. I'm not sure where I can manually specify partitions in this process? Thanks

Comment: You're getting partitions automatically, so there should be 1 per 32M (on NFS file systems) or 1 per 128M (on HDFS).  Definitely sounds like you've got more than that.  Have you looked at the Spark progress bar?  It's possible that your operation isn't CPU limited, but instead IO or network limited.

Comment: If you can post your entire DAG to the question, it may be easier to debug.

Comment: The spark progress bar spends most of it's time at 50% of `[Stage 4:=============================>                             (1 + 1) / 2]` with the progress bar not moving for many hours.

Comment: Interesting.  The Spark progress bar numbers mean, from left to right: number of tasks (partitions) complete, number of tasks in progress, and total number of tasks.  You only have 1 core active, because there are only 2 total partitions to complete!

Comment: Ah, I think I found your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that your CSV files are gzipped.  When Spark reads files, it loads them in parallel, but it can only do this if the file codec is splittable*.  Plain (non-gzipped) text and parquet are splittable, as well as the `bgzip` codec used in genomics (my field).  Your entire files are ending up in one partition each.

Try decompressing the csv.gz files and running this again.  I think you'll see much better results!

- splittable formats mean that if you are given an arbitrary file offset at which to start reading, you can find the beginning of the next record in your block and interpret it.  Gzipped files are not splittable.

Edit: I replicated this behavior on my machine.  Using `sc.textFile` on a 3G gzipped text file produced 1 partition.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks! That's a definite improvement - I see 100% CPU for a while before it drops back down to about 6% and the status is stuck on `[Stage 4:======================================================>(135 + 2) / 137]` for a long time with mem at 92% constant and disk IO and network IO 0. (Also will there be the same performance problem with writing compressed CSV?) Thanks

Comment: Calling `coalesce(1).write(...` means you're forcing 1 task (1 core) to do the entire write step.  Remove the coalesce and try writing in parallel to a non-compressed file -- this may be what caused you to freeze.

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: It gets to stage 5 much much faster without coalesce(1) and without writing to a compressed file. But it now gets "stuck" at end of `[Stage 5:======================================================>(135 + 2) / 137]` with 0% disk and network IO 87% memory use and 12% CPU for a long time. Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your posted pipeline to reflect your new execution model?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by new execution model. The run-time is down from 6.5 hours to 2.5 hours thanks to your suggestions though. Do you have any idea why it gets stuck at the end of stage 5 for so long? Thanks

Comment: I mean, can you update the Spark commands you're calling?  Also, I very much recommend looking at the Spark webui to diagnose performance problems.

Comment: Thanks Tim. In the WebUI we are seeing errors `16/11/07 11:12:58 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool`. Other than that I'm not sure how I can update the Spark commands as I'm not clear why it gets stuck at the end of stage 5 for hours with the CPU at 6% on all nodes of the cluster (we've moved to a cluster to try to improve performance - no joy).

Comment: We also tried re-partitioning the two input dataframes into 16 partitions (as we have 8 cores) but we still have the 6% CPU no network or disk IO and constant 86% memory usage for hours at the end of the job we can't work out what it is caused by. It does most (all?) of its output file writing after the high CPU usage and doesn't seem to write much/anything for the final 2 hours.

Comment: Are you still using `coalesce(1)`?  That will send all results to one core, and that one core will write the entire output file.

Comment: Using the Web UI we have confirmed it completes all stages very fast including the final stage "saveAsTextFile at package.scala:179" up till `Stage Id Description Submitted Duration Tasks: Succeeded/Total Input Output Shuffle Read Shuffle Write
5 saveAsTextFile at package.scala:179
2016/11/09 11:35:11 20 min 
30/32   4.4 GB ` when CPU drops right off and it gets "stuck" for 2 hours before completing.

Comment: This is very odd.  If you kill the job when it looks complete, does the output look right?

Comment: Hi Tim. Its not till the end of the job after 2 hours of "dead zone" that it writes the output files in a burst of network IO to S3. Until then just a _temporary folder exists.

Comment: We have since upgraded to Spark 2.0.2 but still have the same issue with two tasks in the 32 task stage never completing and the box idling over for hours.

Comment: Try looking at the Spark WebUI while it's going.  That can help you see what's spinning without completing

Comment: Hi Tim. Yes I can see the exact step running and the two of 32 tasks that get stuck. I can also see the DAG. Just not sure what to do next! Thanks