# Loading compressed gzipped csv file in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I load a gzip compressed csv file in Pyspark on Spark 2.0 ?

I know that an uncompressed csv file can be loaded as follows:

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("header",          
                                "true").load("myfile.csv")
```

or

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("myfile.csv")
```

Comment: Careful with gzipped CSV files -- you'll get 1 partition per file since they're not splittable.  See this question/answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336485/spark-local-mode-all-jobs-only-use-one-cpu-core/40370994#40370994

Comment: Please note that this would cause performance issues, somehow gzip files are unsplittable and can cause execution in a single cluster !
Here are some of the threads you may want to refer
http://snappishproductions.com/2015/09/28/Troubleshooting-Apache-Spark-GZip.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492967/dealing-with-a-large-gzipped-file-in-spark

Answer (score 20):

I just discovered that the following works with gzipped csv files:

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("myfile.csv")
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution using multiple `csv.gzip` files? It would be really awesome if that works.

Comment: You can use the `*` wildcard - `df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("some_path/*.gz")`. It works across several folders too- `df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("some_path/*/*.gz")`

Answer (score 6):

I am unsure if this changed between the writing of the answers here and when I came to this question, but I would like to insert my findings for the future reference of myself and others who also encounter this same issue. I was loading GZIP compressed CSV files into a PySpark DataFrame on Spark version 2.4.7 and python version 3.7.4 inside of Google's managed Spark-As-A-Service offering aka "Dataproc". The underlying Dataproc image version is [1.5-debian10](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.5) if you want to further investigate the specs.

My problem was I could not successfully read the CSV without all of the input still being garbled. I was able to make one small tweak by changing the ending of the filename so that the file suffix was `.gz` and then things worked perfectly after that. Here is the code to reproduce the issue.

```sh
# This is a shell script to get a dummy file created with 2 different endings
echo 'foo,bar,baz' > test.csv
gzip test.csv
# So now there are 2 files with 2 endings
cp test.csv.gz test_csv
```

I then can run the pyspark job or even an interactive pyspark session (pictured below) then to verify that spark doesn't intelligently detect the file type so much as it looks at the filename and interprets the file type based on its name.

```py
$ pyspark
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  `_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.7
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019 20:35:49)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> filename_noend = 'test_csv'
>>> filename_end = 'test.csv.gz'
>>> schema = 'field1 string,field2 string,field3 string'
>>> df_noend = spark.read.csv(path=filename_noend, schema=schema, header=False)
>>> df_noend.show()
+--------------------+-------------+------+
|              field1|       field2|field3|
+--------------------+-------------+------+
���`test.cs...|�*.�+T+
                      |  null|
+--------------------+-------------+------+

>>> df_end = spark.read.csv(path=filename_end, schema=schema, header=False)
>>> df_end.show()
+------+------+------+
|field1|field2|field3|
+------+------+------+
|   foo|   bar|   baz|
+------+------+------+
>>> exit()
```

Sadly there is no way to specify something like `compression='gzip'` or whatever. So save your gzip compressed files with a `.gz` ending and you are good to go!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `spark.sparkContext.textFile("file.gz")`

The file extension should be `.gz`

Comment: This produces an rdd, not a DataFrame. Is there anyway of reading into a DataFrame directly, instead of having to convert the rdd to a DataFrame ?

Comment: Actually never mind, the following works with gzipped csv files:

```spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("myfile.csv")```

Comment: thanks for the responses .. @Shankar however, this option is only giving me the file names inside the gz file but not the contents of that file

Comment: Edit: I got to correct the extension with proper small case. It was in caps. Thanks.