# AWS Glue -- pass jar file to Glue Job Properly

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a working AWS Glue pyspark script that I'm trying to optimize. The script reads large text gz files, does some light transformation, and then loads them by partition in to a parquet db.   But, many take over two hours to run and some take as much as 8 hours with very little change by adding workers or horsepower.

The core issue: .gz compressed files are un-splittable and standard spark reads the single file into one worker, thus my job does not benefit from spark's parallelization.  Jobs that read, transform, and load even moderately large .gz files (ie. > 1GB) can take hours.   This is a well [documented](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29102) problem for spark newcomers.

Neils Basjes has written a custom compression codec that forces spark to split the file as its uncompressing it in order to parallelize the job.  As I understand it, it has been in and out of support by standard spark.  But, both Neils and I are struggling with the right set of configuration params and script settings to try the codec in a standard Glue 4.0 job.  Because his guides are for a standard EMR or spark cluster, I am struggling to reverse engineer those guides for an AWS Glue ETL job.  I'm not even certain Glue will do it but Glue does appear to support custom jar files which is the core of Neil's codec.

Here is what I've tried but am still getting failures on the spark write after spark initializes, does the lazy read and then fails on the write.

Am using AWS [glue params](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html):

1. Job definition:  --user-jars-first true
   --extra-jars s3://aws-glue-assets-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-us-east-1/jars/  # this path to where I have Neils' jars file "splittablegzip-1.3.jar"
2. In my script I'm trying to follow Neils readme on spark which seemingly uses spark-submit --packages and the maven coordinates for this repo, something I can't (or don't know how to) do on glue, I use conf settings and get an error:

> ```
> spark.conf.set('spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes', 1000 * (1024 ** 2))
> spark.conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'io.compression.codecs:nl.basjes.hadoop.io.compress.SplittableGzipCodec')
>
> >>AnalysisException:  Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.jars.packages. See also 'https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#ddl-statements'
> ```

***I think my problem is likely in the second conf set command.***

When I run my spark read:

```
options = {
            "sep" :'\t',
            "header" : 'false',
            "io.compression.codecs": 'nl.basjes.hadoop.io.compress.SplittableGzipCodec'

        }
df = spark.read.load(
    sm_file,
    format="csv",
   # schema=schema,
    **options,
).count()
```

The job fails with an error:

> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
> botocore.errorfactory.IllegalSessionStateException: An error occurred
> (IllegalSessionStateException) when calling the GetStatement
> operation: Session bd9fb206-9f6b-49d6-897a-c30e0771e0fc unavailable,
> fail to call ReplServer

As Neils points out, I have alternatives which are to pre-process the files (recompress to bz2, un-compress and split) but am trying to find another way as this problem seems quite pernicious here on SA with multiple people struggling with large .gz compressed files.

Opportunity for someone to be the hero and solve this for many of us as shows in related questions!?!

Related SO questions:

1. [Using AWS Glue to convert very big csv.gz (30-40 gb each) to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614265/using-aws-glue-to-convert-very-big-csv-gz-30-40-gb-each-to-parquet)
2. [AWS Glue Crawler - Reading a gzip file of csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827394/aws-glue-crawler-reading-a-gzip-file-of-csv)
3. [How do I split / chunk Large JSON Files with AWS glueContext before converting them to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805267/how-do-i-split-chunk-large-json-files-with-aws-gluecontext-before-converting-t)
4. [Dealing with a large gzipped file in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492967/dealing-with-a-large-gzipped-file-in-spark)