# Using AWS Glue to convert very big csv.gz (30-40 gb each) to parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

There are lots of such questions but nothing seems to help. I am trying to covert quite large csv.gz files to parquet and keep on getting various errors like

```
'Command failed with exit code 1'
```

or

```
An error occurred while calling o392.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-172-31-5-241.eu-central-1.compute.internal, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed
```

. In the metrics monitoring I don't see much of CPU or Memory load. There is ETL data movement but that should be trigger any error when working with S3.

Another problem is that such job runs 4-5 hours before throwing. Is it an expected behavior? CSV files have like 30-40 cols.

I don't know which direction to go. Can Glue overall handle such large files?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem isn't directly connected to the number of DPUs. You have large file and you are using GZIP format which it’s not splittable therefore you have this problem.

I suggest to convert your file from GZIP to bzip2 or lz4. Additionaly you should consider to use partitioning of output data for better performance in the future.

http://comphadoop.weebly.com/

Comment: would be good to offer an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How many DPUs you are using. This [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-debug-capacity.html) gives a nice overview of DPU capacity planning. Hope that helps. There is no definite rulebook from AWS stating how much DPU you need to process a particular size.

Comment: I started with 10. Then tried 50. Now I kicked off 2 similar jobs: with 2 dpus and with 98. Will read the articile now, thank you