# AWS Import large CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

what would be correct set of tools and steps to import ZIPed CSV file from a web site on regular basis?

Logically I need to:

1. Truncate target
2. Download ZIP file
3. Unzip
4. Import (in RDS - any RDS type can be used here)
5. Export to target database (another RDS - SQL Server)

I'm looking at S3, Glue, Lambda, etc...

Comment: `Step Functions`

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts..

1. Mentioned AWS Step Functions is good approach to implement the whole workflow in one place.
2. You don't need to implement unzip step each case, because a lot of tools can read data directly from compressed file, for instance AWS Glue.
3. If you have very big file you need to remember that some compression formats aren't splitable. It is important for example if you use AWS Glue. More information about that on ([Using AWS Glue to convert very big csv.gz (30-40 gb each) to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614265/using-aws-glue-to-convert-very-big-csv-gz-30-40-gb-each-to-parquet/52630553#52630553)).
4. You can use AWS Glue, but also AWS Data Pipeline. More about the differences on https://aws.amazon.com/glue/faqs/  (Q: When should I use AWS Glue vs. AWS Data Pipeline?)
5. Most of db engines have a dedicated data import tool, for instance  PostgreSql/Aurora PostgreSQL/Redshift - COPY command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html), MySql, Aurora MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html)
6. The advantage of the tools mentioned in point no 5 is that they use the internal db mechanism to load the data, it is more faster than in case of using JDBC or other drivers. For instance, as I remember AWS Glue uses this approach only in case of AWS Redshift.
7. More information about the architectures you can find in (https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/)

I hope this information will help you.