# Converting JSON .gz files into Delta Tables

Tags: json, databricks, delta-lake, tar.gz

I have Data Dog log data archives streaming to an Azure Blob stored in a single 150MB JSON file compressed in a 15MB .gz file. These are being generated every 5 minutes. Need to do some analytics on this data. What is the most efficient and cost effective solution to get this data into delta lake?

From what I understand the driver that unpacks this data can only run on a single node spark cluster, which will take a very long time and cost a lot of DBU's.

Has anyone done this successfully without breaking the bank?

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand the driver that unpacks this data can only run on a single node spark cluster, which will take a very long time and cost a lot of DBU's.

Yes, that's the big downside of `gzip` format - it is not splitable and therefore cannot be distributed across all your workers and cores - the Driver has to load a file in its entirety and decompress it in a single batch. [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493487/6870955)  related to this question.

The only sensible workaround I've used myself is to make Driver have only few cores but as powerful ones as possible - I assume, since you are using Azure Blob, then you are using Databricks on Azure as well and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes) you can find all Azure VM types - just have to pick the one with fastest cores.

Comment: Not a driver, but one of the workers...